# How can we model a photon's electric field and magnetic field in empty space?

Tags: electromagnetism

If you search around the web, there are absolutely horrible diagrams that look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAIqd.jpg

What am I looking at here? For a photon propagating through space, is it essentially pulsing as it travels? How does this field get induced by a traveling photon?  Does it really only produce force in the directions indicated by the diagram above or is that an approximation? Do the peaks propagate at the same speed as the photon? I have only a rudimentary understanding of Maxwell's equations and am trying to close the gap. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How familiar are you with vector calculus? I can try to adapt my answer to that level. And how much of EM theory have you covered so far?

Comment: I know calculus/vector calculus but only took one course on EM. I covered Gauss' law, in essence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the photon does not have an electric field and magnetic field. Unfortunately, without a proper understanding of Maxwell's equations you really cannot understand electromagnetic waves. Second, photons are not a classical phenomenon and they don't fit the Maxwell picture but we will come to that later.

### I. What is the EM wave?

Imagine a (classical) charged particle at rest. This particle thus creates an electric field around it which would be described by Coulomb's law. This field is static (i.e., it does not change with time). If you were to accelerate this particle you will introduce both time and spatial changes in this electric field.

What Maxwell's equations tell you is that a changing electric field *induces* a magnetic field. And a changing magnetic field *induces* an electric field. In particular in free space we say,

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{\nabla} \times \mathbf{E} &= -\frac{\partial \mathbf{B}} {\partial t} \\
\mathbf{\nabla} \times \mathbf{B} &= \mu_0\left(\mathbf{J} + \varepsilon_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf{E}} {\partial t} \right)
\end{align}
$$

Here $\mathbf{E}$ denotes the electric field and $\mathbf{B}$ denotes the magnetic field and $\mathbf{J}$ is the current density field (fancy term to describe how much current is there at different points in space and time).

In simpler words, these equations tell you that an infinitesimal *time* change in the magnetic field introduces a [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)) (*infinitesimal circulation*) in an electric field. And an infinitesimal time change in the electric field (or a current) introduces a curl in the magnetic field. The two fields are clearly linked to each other and with a bit of vector calculus you can reduce Maxwell's equations to the following two second order differential equations:

$$
\begin{align}
\left(c^2\nabla^2 - \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \right) \mathbf{E} &= \mathbf{0} \\
\left(c^2\nabla^2 - \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} \right) \mathbf{B} &= \mathbf{0}
\end{align}
$$

These equations tell you that once there is a changing change [aka second order change] in one field it produces a wave (solutions to the two differential equations above) which propagates in spacetime with second order changes in electric field inducing second order changes magnetic fields and vice versa. The diagram you have attached is trying to show you how these fields fluctuate in space. They fluctuate in time also and I think the following diagram from Wikipedia shows this a bit better:

[image: Transverse EM wave]

## II. What is the photon?

Maxwell's theory of light is that of a wave. His equations don't describe what a photon is. Photon is a construct of the quantum theory. In the original quantum theory, Einstein described them as the minimum unit with which an electromagnetic field could transfer its energy or momentum. In the simplest case where you have a monochromatic EM wave of frequency $f$, each packet transfers an energy of $hf$ from the source(s) of the field to the interacting object(s) [atom for example].

Quantum field theory takes the view that particles are excitations of an underlying field. In that sense, you can think of photons as excitations of the electromagnetic field.

It is wrong to picture this photon as moving up or down or sideways. If you really want to picture the photon going from point A to point B, think of it as going in a straight line (though strictly speaking that picture is wrong also). The diagram you have attached plots the $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ field vectors at each point along that line on which the wave is travelling. It is not showing matter oscillating like waves on the surface of a pond.